# Why (and how ?) does sqlalchemy bypass FK constrainsts with sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

While I was doing unit testing, I wrote some code that I knew wouldn't pass because of foreign constrainst... Except it did.

This is an example :

```
import os
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
  os.unlink('test.db')
except:
  pass
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')

Base = declarative_base()

class Test1(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Test1'
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key = True)

class Test2(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Test2'
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key = True)
  link = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey(Test1.id), index = True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker()

session = Session(bind=engine)

session.add(Test2(id=1, link=2)) # <-- should raise an error because 2 not in Test1
session.commit()
session.add(Test1(id=1))
session.commit()
session.add(Test2(id=2, link=1)) #ok
session.commit()
session.add(Test2(id=3, link=42)) # <-- should raise an error because 42 not in Test1
session.commit()
```

I declare a simple database, a table `Test1` with a PK `id`, and a second table `Test2` with a PK id and a FK constrainst on `Test2.link` to reference `Test1.id`. Then, I insert some values that would break the FK.

The FK seems to work because if I open a sqlite db browser, I can't put these same values...

Why and how sqlalchemy bypasses the FK ?

Note : I haven't tried on another db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you turn on enforcement in SQLite?

```
> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020197/foreign-key-isnt-being-enforced). To enable this in code, one can use

```
engine = create_engine(database_url)
engine.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON')
```

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys) has an example for using listeners/events to run this on connect.

```
def _fk_pragma_on_connect(dbapi_con, con_record):
    dbapi_con.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON')

from sqlalchemy import event
event.listen(engine, 'connect', _fk_pragma_on_connect)
```

Comment: Nice ! I was stucking googling the wrong question...
I adopted this solution that seems smarter : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15542046/1745291