# SQLAlchemy expression language and SQLite's on delete cascade

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have two related tables namely `users` and `roles` and the relationship between them is many-to-many, so another association table `userroles` also exists.

The `userroles` table keeps track of the associated `users` and `roles` rows using foreign keys. For the foreign keys the `ondelete` parameter is set to `"CASCADE"` to get rid of the association row if any of the associated elements are being deleted.

This is my setup:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa


engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
metadata = sa.MetaData()


userroles = sa.Table(
    "userroles",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("user_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE")),
    sa.Column("role_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("roles.id", ondelete="CASCADE")),
)


users = sa.Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("name", sa.String),
)


roles = sa.Table(
    "roles",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("name", sa.String),
)

metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()

conn.execute(users.insert().values(name="Joe"))
conn.execute(roles.insert().values(name="Admin"))
conn.execute(roles.insert().values(name="User"))
conn.execute(userroles.insert().values(user_id=1, role_id=1))
```

However when I delete the `Admin` role which has the unique id of `1`, the associated row is not being deleted from the `userroles` table. Why?

What am I missing here?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3020197/6560549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay it seems like you need to enforce foreign keys for sqlite. So based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15542046/6337523) one should do:

```py
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlite3 import Connection as SQLite3Connection

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def _set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    if isinstance(dbapi_connection, SQLite3Connection):
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
        cursor.close()
```